# Authentication in a Capacitor Next.js App

Tags: firebase, next.js, capacitor, next-auth

I am building a Native Mobile App with Next.js and Capacitor. I am however having trouble with authentication.

I tried with Next Auth but all the Documentation I am finding is either about Next 13 and I have trouble adapting it Next 14 either doesn't include Capacitor.

I initialized my project following this [tutorial](https://galaxies.dev/nextjs-and-capacitor) and I tried using NextAuth following this [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=md65iBX5Gxg) but I get this error

> Error: Page "/api/auth/[...netxauth]/route" is missing exported
> function "generateStaticParams()", which is required with "output:
> export" config.

Here is my `app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts` file :

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GitHubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";

export const AuthOptions = {
    providers : [
        GitHubProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID ?? "",
            clientSecret : process.env.GITHUB_SECRET ?? "",
        }),
    ],
};

export const handler = NextAuth(AuthOptions);
export {handler as GET, handler as POST};
```

Is there any way to make it work or are they incompatible? Should I  just switch to next 13 or an other framework?  Is there a framework that works well with capacitor?